# Huawei G700-U10 GPS keeps enabling itself after a while

Tags: gps, huawei-g700

Is there a method to track which apps are turning on my GPS to access my location?
I just realized today that my GPS was turned on last night. 
I turned it off as soon as I noticed, but then it turns back on immediately with the icon flashing in the notification area. The slide bar is also switched to "enabled" in my settings.

It happens like a ghost moving behind the scenes so it is pretty scary.

Is this a spy phone, app(s) problem or Huawei issue?

It was not like this during the immediate purchase which leads me to believe it just happen recently.

Comment: Where is GPS located on hiwei g700?

Answer (score 1):

You can install an app to see what apps asks permission to use GPS then you can see which app of all of them is using your gps but rulling out them one by one. Propably FB or another SNS app did this. If Huawei wanted to spy on you there are better ways to do so. One good app to start with is F-Secure App Permission and can be found here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsecure.app.permissions.privacy&hl=en